# Get more SSL debug information

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl

In order to get more debug info from SSL I can add line below in java command line.

```
 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```

But how to set this option in Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

In your Eclipse environment, select the java project, right-click, and select Properties.

Click Run/Debug Settings.

Select New... > Java Application, and click the Environment tab.

Comment: That's not an environment variable, but a Java property. So, in the launch configuration `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` have to be added in the _Arguments_ tab as _VM argument_, not in the _Environment_ tab.